# one php website never runs on IIS

Tags: php, iis-7

Need some hint:

I have installed PHP on Windows Server 2008. The phpinfo() can display. And I even have wordpress running. Well, without a database, it only shows a page with a link to the installation guide. But it is running.

However, the web site I need to use, just never loads:

The website cannot display the page 
 HTTP 500
   Most likely causes:
•The website is under maintenance.
•The website has a programming error.

What you can try: 
     Retype the address.

```
 Go back to the previous page.
```

Can anyone give me some hint? What went wrong?

Comment: Turn off Friendly HTTP Error Messages, both in IE (if you're using that) and in IIS7. This will give you a more detailed response as to what exactly is going on. IMHO, I wouldn't install PHP on IIS as it's just not stable enough for production, nor do I ever recommend MySQL on Windows. If you're going out for a nice steak, don't buy it at McDonalds...

Comment: Check your log files for the specific error. IIS error reporting is childish at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the Serverside Includes is not selected when installing the FastCGI. Need to enable that. Hope this helps some other readers.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a parse error in the PHP code. Can you run command line php on the script? That may give you a more detailed error message including an offending line number.